# Scene Builedr не открывает fxml файл

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, java-8

Здравствуйте. Не могу понять. Scene Bulder 2.0 не открывает 2 из 3х файлов. И при этом эти файлы чуть раньше им отрывались.

Вот содержимое одного из файлов которые не открываются:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0"
            prefWidth="600.0" stylesheets="@../css/DarkTheme.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <top>
        <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <menus>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close"/>
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete"/>
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About"/>
                    </items>
                </Menu>
            </menus>
        </MenuBar>
    </top>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: Посмотрите логи Scene Buileder там должна быть причина.

Comment: @ВалераНикитюк запости как ответ самому себе, чтобы те, кто найдет этот вопрос позже, нашли ответ.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вот нашел ответ [stackoverflow.com/a/31667857/6944125](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31667857/6944125). всем спасибо за помощь